# C# gridview not working properly

Tags: c#, database, gridview

I recently started learning `C#` and im stuck with a `gridview` and `database`.

I have a `textbox` and a `button` which will **add** the text in the textbox to my `gridview`.
but its not working as I want it to.

**Problems:**

the text from my textbox is not shown. when i click the button the 2nd time i get the following ***error "Cannot add an entity that allready exsists".***

if I click the array my self a new line is generated but it only shows numbers like, " -1, -2, -3" for each array..
if i try to change the numbers to text, the program fails big time.

This is what I have used;
gridview -linked it with my database
LINQ to SQL Classes
Service-based Database

this is my codes. trying to keep it simple as possible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace database_test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Database1DataSet db = new Database1DataSet();
        DataClasses1DataContext dblink = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        Table1 tabel = new Table1();


        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabel.Materiale = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);
            dblink.Table1s.InsertOnSubmit(tabel);
            dblink.SubmitChanges();


        }

        private void database1DataSetBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.table1TableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be impressive for a WinForms application.

Comment: is it window or web ?? looking at public partial class Form1 : Form,using System.Windows.Forms; seem window and you taged grivdiew ??... If web do post .apsx code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common issue when startin asp.net webforms is forgetting calling `DataBind()` method, after some changes, editing etc. This method inits data to view control in order to render it.

Comment: can you give an example of DataBind() ? im pretty much noob to this and need everything to be as easy it can get.

Comment: Check this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) page, there is code sample to binding.